# Spring 4 web - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have some problems upgrading spring version (3.2.6 to 4.2.1).

I get 500 Internal server error when trying to get css and js files related to login page.
At the server side I see the exception: 
'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0]'

After debugging it I saw that in 'ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest()' method there's a check for the response status before setting any status to the response - causing 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0]' exception.

The check is done in:
'ServletWebRequest.isCompatibleWithConditionalRequests(ServletWebRequest.java:244)'

which is called in 'ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:240)'

When the status change phase happen only in 'writeContent(response, resource)' ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:271.

I've found a workaround - use a custom 'ResourceHttpRequestHandler' that sets the response status 200 when response status is 0 before handling the request.

Any idea how to fix it in a cleaner way? or is it a bug?

Stacktrace:

```
2015-09-16 17:17:14.964:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp749664947-21: 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1644)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at com.myApp.webapp.RequestParameterToAttributeFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterToAttributeFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at com.myApp.webapp.PersonalizationFilter.doFilter(PersonalizationFilter.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at com.myApp.webapp.GenericWrappingFilter.doFilter(GenericWrappingFilter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0]
    at org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(HttpStatus.java:488)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.isCompatibleWithConditionalRequests(ServletWebRequest.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.checkNotModified(ServletWebRequest.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:240)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1644)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at com.myApp.webapp.RequestParameterToAttributeFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterToAttributeFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at com.myApp.webapp.PersonalizationFilter.doFilter(PersonalizationFilter.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at com.myApp.webapp.GenericWrappingFilter.doFilter(GenericWrappingFilter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I've met the same issue this morning, upgrading from 4.1.7 to 4.2.1.  My resources are correctly tagged with security="none". I have no good solution so far, and have resorted to (hopefully temporarily) adding a new "httpStatusFixFilter", setting HttpStatus.OK when the received code is 0.

Comment: @Elegie that's exactly what I did. Hope we'll find a better solution...

Comment: Upgrading from Spring 3 to 4 today and ran into this issue. It is maddening, and I can't find a solution anywhere. Guess I am going to workaround with the filter as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed with [SPR-13516](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13516) and has been shipped with [Spring Framework 4.2.2](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR/fixforversion/15267/).

Answer (score 1):

The exception message indicates your server side code generated a response with status code 0, which is invalid. If you check valueOf method of  HttpStatus class you will see the exception message (spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.java) :-

```
public static HttpStatus valueOf(int statusCode) {
        for (HttpStatus status : values()) {
            if (status.value == statusCode) {
                return status;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No matching constant for [" + statusCode + "]");
    }
```

I see this as the main issue on error stacktrace:-

```
at com.myApp.webapp.GenericWrappingFilter.doFilter(GenericWrappingFilter.java:100)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1624)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
```

It seems your filter is active on these non-secured css & js items. You have to make them filter free with config something like this :-

```
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/login.jsp*" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/js/**" security="none"/>
```

Note:- i assumed you have all JS files within JS folder on classpath.

Comment: I know that it throws the exception. The question is why status code is 0 at this point.

Comment: Can you share the full error stack trace along with some insight of your project so i could help you more precisely.

Comment: The stacktrace is already attached. My project is a spring project with many configuration files so I cannot attach them all. The error happens when I try to get a css or js file that is not secured - and spring handles it using ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Comment: Pls check my comments above on main answer around filtering.

Comment: I already have the security="none" configuration. And my filter only call 'chain.doFilter(request, response);' so its not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain this is a bug in the latest versions (4.2 and 4.2.1) of Spring to do with testing of content modification for caching static resources. The line appears to be in this commit:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/0175068cab7d294b6cce4369cbd7745dd03198ab#diff-40591a69c61c7ec1f211737fbf40b4ac

It gets move around a bit in subsequent commits, but that is the first time I can see the status code having its content tested without testing its existence.

I downgraded from 4.2.1 to 4.1.7 to make it go away.

EDIT: See answer from @BrianClozel as this is fixed in 4.2.2

Comment: Thanks Greg for reaching out to the Spring team; we'd rather fix this for you instead of letting you stuck with workarounds. There's an issue logged for this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13516

Comment: Thanks @BrianClozel. If it helps at all, we don't really touch or configure ResourceHttpRequestHandler at all. It is just using the XML config from MVC: `<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/WEB-INF/assets/"/>`