# dispather-servlet and mvc:resources conflict error: No matching constant for [0]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resources

I've been reading all questions related to this topic for several hours but I haven't found a solution to my problem. My spring version is 4.2.1-release.

### web.xml:

```
...
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,/WEB-INF/security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

### applicatinContext.xml:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/lib/**" location="/lib/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/app/**" location="/app/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.controller" />
```

### dispather-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/myview/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

### com.my.controller.IndexController.java

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String index(HttpServletRequest request, Model map) {
       return "index";
   }
}
```

I want my controllers to be in the root of my application (localhost:8084/MyApp/). My IndexController works fine, but my resources does not!
For example when I request an image (localhost:8084/MyApp/img/img.png) I face this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0]
```

with root cause:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0]
at org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(HttpStatus.java:488)
at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.isCompatibleWithConditionalRequests(ServletWebRequest.java:244)
at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.checkNotModified(ServletWebRequest.java:181)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:240)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug in the latest versions (4.2 and 4.2.1) of Spring.

I downgraded from 4.2.1 to 4.1.7 to make it go away. It works fine!!!!!

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612027/spring-4-web-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-matching-constant-for-0).